# What's wrong with my projectile update function?

Tags: c++, game-physics

Here is all the relevant code.

This gets run when the projectile is initialized:

```
slope = (yTarget - yPos) / (xTarget - xPos);
if (xTarget >= xPos)
    xDir = 1;
else
    xDir = -1;
if (yTarget >= yPos)
    yDir = 1;
else
    yDir = -1;
```

And this gets run every update which happens every gameloop:

```
xPos += t*speed*xDir;
yPos += t*speed*yDir * abs(slope);
```

XTarget and yTarget are where the projectile should go and xPos and yPos are where the projectile currently is. Speed is 1 for now so just ignore it and t is the number of ticks (ms) that have gone by since the last update. (usually 0-2 on my computer) It all works fine except that the bullet speed seems to be dependent on (xTarget - xPos)' distance to 0, the projectile speeding up the closer it is. I'll try to explain it visually. If I shoot to the right or left of my character the bullet moves at the desired speed. However, if I shoot above or below the character, it shoots extremely quickly. Can someone tell me a way to fix this or a better way to code this whole thing? Thanks.

Comment: Can't spot the problem. However another approach is to keep track of the firing time `t0` and recompute `xPos`, `yPos` based on current time relative to `t0`. I.e. use a single absolute calculation rather than a series of increments.

Comment: I really like this idea. I'll try to implement this now.
EDIT: Oh wait, I just realized this wont help. I'm pretty sure the problem lies with the slope and I'm still gonna have to use that.

Comment: On each step, the position advances by `t` in X direction, and `t*slope` in Y direction. So the distance is `t*sqrt(1 + slope^2)`. Now it should be clear that, the bigger the slope, the higher the speed. In the limit, when shooting straight up, slope is infinite, and so is speed.

Comment: Thanks Igor. That was my suspicion. How can I fix it though if i still need to move Y by slope to get an accurate movement?

Comment: Use these formulas: `vx = (xTarget - xPos) / T`, `vy = (yTarget - yPos) / T`. Here `vx` and `vy` is speed in X and Y directions correspondingly, and `T` is the total time it should take the bullet to reach target. Then you can advance with `xPos += t*vx; yPos += t*vy;`, or using absolute calculations as @Keith suggested (the formulas for that are left as an exercise for the reader).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dx = xTarget - xPos;
dy = yTarget - yPos;
norm = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
if (norm != 0) {
    dx /= norm;
    dy /= norm;
}
```

Later:

```
xPos += t*speed*dx;
yPos += t*speed*dy;
```

Comment: This is not very good check: `if (norm != 0)`. It is much safer to check it this way: `if (norm > 1.e-6)` (or something like this).

Comment: I don't make any assumptions on the scale of his data.  What if before normalizing, dx = 0 and dy = 1.e-7?  With my code, it normalizes to dx = 0, dy = 1.  With your code, dy remains at 1.e-7.  Now let's suppose speed is 1.e-8.  What should take the bullet 10 units of time to reach the destination will now take 100000000 units of time.  If norm is small it only means that dx and dy were small as well.

Comment: Thank you for explanation! It looks that in this case we don't need epsilon testing to avoid division by zero (my first reaction was based on allergy on constructions like `if (a == b)` where `a` and `b` are `double`s). But in this case it looks acceptable.